# Automatically refreshing a browser when a particular file in a directory changes?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, safari, internet-explorer

Are there any add-ons that will cause a browser to automatically refresh a page when a particular file changes on disk?

Comment: can you give any more details on what you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Andy Sure, I have some unit tests that display their results as an HTML page, and my browser displays them.  I want the page to automatically refresh when regenerate the html page that displays the results of the test.

Comment: Same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346716/how-do-i-make-firefox-auto-refresh-on-file-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use a plugin-for-a-plugin to do this. In particular [this auto-reload plugin](http://vimperator.kurinton.net/plugins/auto_reload.html) which works with the [Vimperator plugin](http://vimperator.org/vimperator) for Firefox.

There's also [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/) directly for Firefox, but I've never tried it personally.

Comment: Sweet!  I'll have to give that a try.  I use Vim but I haven't really gotten used to Vimperator for Mozilla, maybe I'll have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no extensions/functionalities in Chrome to do exactly what you want. But there are options to reload the file with set intervals.

For example ChromeReload or Auto-Reloader are 2 good examples of such extensions. You can configure the interval to your liking in both.

Answer (score 0):

[Tincr](http://tin.cr/) is a Chrome extension that does what you need.