# Refresh CSS in browser with BBEdit

Tags: css, web-development

I want to refresh the CSS in my browser when I save a change to the CSS file with BBEdit.

There is a browser plugin called live reload which does this, but it crashes when chrome inspector is open. There are js codes you can save as bookmarks that are supposed to work when you click them, but none of these work for me locally.

Can BBEdit fresh a page or just refresh a pages's CSS when a CSS file is saved? Ideally id work with Chrome, but if BBEdit provides its own browser (as Espresso does) this would also work ok.

Comment: How about just editing the CSS in Chrome? You can set up a workspace and edit the CSS thought the Sources panel in the DevTools.

Comment: Im using SASS so this wont work for me.

Comment: As suggested in http://superuser.com/questions/148887/automatically-refreshing-a-browser-when-a-particular-file-in-a-directory-changes, you might want to try [tincr](http://tin.cr/)

Answer (score -1):

As Oliver Salzburg suggested, Tincr works.